# Finding the latest entry if entry does not exist in a diff based database

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, where-clause

I have a database consisting of the following tables:

```
function
id    |    name

version
id    |    name

data_table
id | function_id | version_id | date | arbitrary_data1
```

I insert the data by parsing the files.
If a function has changed in a new version I store the diff for that function.
If it has not changed, no data is inserted even if the function physically exists in the new version.
So technically I only store new data if the function in the file has been updated.

Now I need a few complicated queries that make the diff based database seem like a normal database,
where each version has complete data from the previous versions.

Example of what the data_table may contain:

```
data_table
id | function_id | version_id | date          | arbitrary_data
1    1             1            2012-01-01      0
2    2             1            2012-01-01      150
3    1             2            2012-01-02      100
```

I need a query which gives me the arbitrary_data and date for every version for a specific function.

Expected result example for function_id=1:

```
date          | arbitrary_data
2012-01-01      0                           <-- version 1
2012-01-02      100                         <-- version 2
```

The problem I am having is because of the missing rows when a file has not been updated in "this" version. If I were to extract the data for function #2 for example, the data for the second version would not be returned since it is not inserted in the DB.

Now the challenge is to produce complete data (data for every file) for each version.

The query needs to:
Select arbitrary_data and date for every version; if there is no entry for a specific version: **find the latest previous file entry** and
select arbitrary_data from that row instead. (date should still be selected from the original row/version)

It has to be SQLite compatible and preferably fast.

I have a set of queries combined with some logic/scripting in Python which does this, but the execution time is about 1 second per version; which is way too slow for what I need. Below is the Python code:

```
def get_data(self, function_id):

    #fvs is short for fileversions!

    #Gets the function ID and for each version ID
    all_fvs = self._conn.execute('''SELECT * FROM
                                    (SELECT id as function_id FROM function WHERE id = ?)
                                    CROSS JOIN
                                    (SELECT id as version_id from version)
                                    ''', [function_id]).fetchall()

    #Gets the function ID for each version ID that has been registered to the data_table
    registered_fvs = self._conn.execute('''SELECT function_id, version_id
                                            FROM data_table
                                            WHERE function_id = ?
                                            LIMIT 1
                                            ''', [function_id]).fetchall()

    #Gets the function ID for each version ID that has been registered to the data_table with incomplete arbitrary_data
    incomplete_registered_fvs = self._conn.execute('''SELECT arbitrary_data, version_id
                                                    FROM data_table
                                                    WHERE (arbitrary_data IS NULL OR date IS NULL)
                                                    GROUP BY version_id''').fetchall()

    #Gets the arbitrary_data we want for all the rows corresponding to registered_fvs
    data_set = self._conn.execute('''SELECT arbitrary_data, date from data_table
                                    WHERE function_id = ?
                                    ''', [function_id]).fetchall()

    #Converts the lists to counters so that we can perform set operations on them
    all_fvs_counter = Counter(all_fvs)
    registered_fvs_counter = Counter(registered_fvs)
    incomplete_registered_fvs_counter = Counter(incomplete_registered_fvs)

    #Filter out the registered fvs from all fvs
    non_registered_fvs = (all_fvs_counter-registered_fvs_counter)-incomplete_registered_fvs_counter

    #For all the versions that aren't registered, we fetch the latest value of a previous version which was registered
    for (function, version) in non_registered_fvs:
        data_set.append(self._conn.execute('''SELECT arbitrary_data, date
                                                FROM data_table
                                                WHERE function_id = ?
                                                AND date <= (SELECT date FROM data_table WHERE version_id = ? LIMIT 1)
                                                ORDER BY date DESC
                                                LIMIT 1
                                                ''', [function, version]).fetchone())

    return data_set
```

Comment: @dani-h . . . Sample data and desired results can do a lot to clarify a question.

Comment: Does "for each version" mean that the query must return data for all versions, or for one specific version?

Comment: For all versions. Basically if it's missing file data get data from the most recent version and add it to the missing version. I'm not sure how to explain it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Generate all possible combinations of files and versions and then join in the table to get the data you need:

```
select f.file_id, f.version_id, fv.data
from (select distinct file_id from fileversions) f cross join
     (select distinct version_id from fileversions) v left join
     fileversions fv
     on fv.file_id = f.file_id and
        fv.version_id = f.version_id;
```

Files that don't have a particular version will have `NULL` for the `data` column.

It is a bit harder to fill in data from the previous version.  You can do this as:

```
select f.file_id, f.version_id,
       (select fv.data
        from fileversions fv
        where fv.file_id = f.file_id and
              fv.version_id <= f.version_id
        order by fv.version_id desc
        limit 1
       ) as data
from (select distinct file_id from fileversions) f cross join
     (select distinct version_id from fileversions) v
```

Comment: "It is a bit harder to fill in data from the previous version", if the previous version does not have the file, but 4 versions back the file exists - will this still work?

Answer (score 1):

First, we want all combinations of files and versions:

```
SELECT file.id,
       version.id
FROM file
CROSS JOIN version
```

The matching data is the data for the same file, with the largest version that is not larger than the wanted version:

```
SELECT file.id,
       version.id,
       (SELECT id
        FROM data
        WHERE file_id = file.id         -- same file
          AND version_id <= version.id  -- same or earlier version
        ORDER BY version_id DESC        -- largest version first
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS data_id
FROM file
CROSS JOIN version
```

It would be possible to look up multiple columns from the `data` table, but this would require multiple subqueries.
It is a better idea to use the `data.id` that we already have looked up to join with the `data` table:

```
SELECT IDs.version_id,
       data.*
FROM (SELECT version.id AS version_id,
             (SELECT id
              FROM data
              WHERE file_id = file.id
                AND version_id <= version.id
              ORDER BY version_id DESC
              LIMIT 1
             ) AS data_id
      FROM file
      CROSS JOIN version) AS IDs
JOIN data ON IDs.data_id = data.id
ORDER BY IDs.version_id,
         data.file_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(maxDate.date), dt.arbitrary_data, f.id, v.id
from function f
cross join version v
inner join data_table dt
on dt.function_id = f.id
and dt.version_id <= v.id
left join data_table noIntermediate
on dt.function_id = noIntermediate.function_id
and noIntermediate.version_id <= v.id
and noIntermediate.version_id > dt.version_id
inner join data_table maxDate
on maxDate.version_id = v.id
where noIntermediate.function_id is null
group by f.id, v.id, dt.arbitrary_data
```

This query is based on a cross join between all functions and versions. For each function it gets from data_table the greatest version of that function that is no greater than the current iterated version. This is accomplished with an anti-join that checks there exists no version between those two.
To get the date of the version instead of the date of the arbitrary_data row I had to add another join and a group by. On the select, instead of max() it could be min() or avg(). All rows in the group should have the same date, any row can do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.  I very much simplified/mangled the table definitions, and this is done on postgresql, so actual sqlite code will vary.  But the core ideas should work, I've done this before elsewhere.

The clever bit in the view.  This subselect criteria on version.vname is what sqllite needs to be able to do.

```
drop view i f exists func_data_calc; 
drop table if exists versions;

/* and you would probably store things like the dates for the version on this table */
create table versions (vname varchar(20));

drop table if exists func_data;

/* very basic table. stores a function name, the version it refers to and the arb data*/
create table func_data (funcname varchar(20), vname varchar(20), arb_data varchar(20));

/* the trick here is that we pull up the latest arbitrary data 
for a function, for the most recent 
version that is not greater than the version
coming from the version table*/

create view func_data_calc (funcname, vname, arb_data) 
as select funcname, versions.vname, arb_data 
from func_data, versions
where func_data.vname = 
(select max(vname) 
 from func_data s 
 where func_data.funcname = s.funcname 
 and s.vname <= versions.vname);

/* test it */
insert into func_data (funcname, vname, arb_data) 
values ('func1', 'ver01', 'data func1 ver01');

/* oh, no, func1 has nothing for ver02, wasn't touched*/

insert into func_data (funcname, vname, arb_data) 
values ('func2', 'ver01', 'data func2 ver01');

insert into func_data (funcname, vname, arb_data) 
values ('func2', 'ver02', 'data func2 ver02');

/* insert some dummy version data from the function_data*/
insert into versions (vname) select distinct vname from func_data;


select * from func_data_calc
order by funcname, vname;
```

The result of the select?  Notice how func1 has ver02 data, even if it points back to the diff for ver01?  The version = (select max(version)... above is what plugs the holes.

```
funcname|vname|arb_data
"func1";"ver01";"data func1 ver01"
"func1";"ver02";"data func1 ver01"
"func2";"ver01";"data func2 ver01"
"func2";"ver02";"data func2 ver02"
```

Note one thing that needs adding - a closure mechanism indicating that a function doesn't exist anymore as of a certain version.